# Getting error, when i try "sudo apt-get update"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, apt, apt-get

I installed again Ubuntu 18.04 now. After, i tried update and upgrade commands. Upgrade command executed very well. But, update command didn't executed and gave error output. You can view error under:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err:2 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
  Could not resolve 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: similar question : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280199/apt-installation-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server tr.archive.ubuntu.com isn't available right now, if you try to access it in your browser you get a 404 error. You can probably remove the `tr.` from in front of the the `archive.` in /etc/apt/sources.list, and your command will work.

You can do this with your text editor(nano just an example) like this

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Or you can use sed like this

```
sudo sed -i 's|http://tr.|http://|' /etc/apt/sources.list
```